Let $B$ be a von Neumann subalgebra of $A$. Is it true that $L^2(B)\subseteq L^2(A)$?
Let $A\subseteq B$ be a unital normal inclusion of von Neumann algebras. Is it true that this induces an isometry of the standard Hilbert spaces
$$L^2(A)\to L^2(B)?$$
I'm not sure if I can expect this to be true in general. Indeed, if we fix an nsf weight $\varphi$ on $B$, then there does not seem to be way that the restriction $\varphi\vert_A$ is still nsf (it is still faithful and normal, but it appears semi-finiteness might fail).
Is this true or are there any nice counterexamples?

I haven’t dealt with standard forms of von Neumann algebras in general much, so I’m not completely sure. But it seems to me that if such an isometry were to exist, then there should be an isometry $A_\ast \to B_\ast$ as well, which would then dualize to a normal conditional expectation $B \to A$. So any inclusions of von Neumann algebras that admit no normal conditional expectation should be a counterexample.

@DavidGao Tjanks for the comment. I'm not entirely sure why this isometry induces the map $A_\to B_$? How does this work?

I suppose this depends on what exactly do you mean by this “induces” an isometry of the standard Hilbert spaces. I’ll make some assumptions and write an answer.

The problem statement in the title seems to have $A$ and $B$ the other way around from the way they are used in the body of the question.

I’m assuming here, by inducing an isometry $v: L^2(A) \to L^2(B)$, the isometry must satisfy the following two conditions:

$va = av$ for all $a \in A$;
$vJ = Jv$ where $J$ is the modular conjugation.

Note that $1$ also implies $v^\ast a = av^\ast$ for all $a \in A$ since $A$ is self-adjoint, and $2$ also implies $v^\ast J = Jv^\ast$ since $J$ is an antilinear isometry. Now, I claim that the existence of such an $v$ implies the existence of a normal conditional expectation $E: B \to A$ given by $E(b) = v^\ast bv$. Clearly, thus defined, $E$ is normal and has norm at most $1$. We need to show that $E(b) \in A$ for all $b \in B$ and $E(a) = a$ for all $a \in A$.
Now, for the first claim, since $A = A’’ = (JAJ)’$, it suffices to show $v^\ast bvJaJ = JaJv^\ast bv$ for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. We have,
$$\begin{split}
v^\ast bvJaJ &= v^\ast bJvaJ\\
&= v^\ast bJavJ\\
&= v^\ast bJaJv\\
&= v^\ast JaJbv\\
&= Jv^\ast aJbv\\
&= Jav^\ast Jbv\\
&= JaJv^\ast bv
\end{split}$$
For the second claim, we simply observe that $v^\ast av = v^\ast va = a$ whenever $a \in A$.
Hence, whenever the inclusion $A \to B$ is s.t. no normal conditional expectation $E: B \to A$ exists, we must have no such isometry $v$ exist.
